# Replace fetched search results on each new search in react-infinite-scroll-component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-scroll

In this app, I'm fetching images from the Unsplash API (with an Express back end, React front end). On page load, general images appear (rendered inside the `react-infinite-scroll-component`). If you search for a term, the `search` state changes from false to true. I use a ternary operator to conditionally render the images inside the infinite scroll component:

```
{this.state.newSearch || this.state.search ? this.state.searchImages.map(image =>
          <Image key={image.id} image={image} />
        ) : this.state.images.map(image =>
          <Image key={image.id} image={image} />
 )}
```

The images that first loaded (from `componentDidMount`) are replaced after you type in the input and press enter, but if you type something else and hit enter, the new search results are instead added to the end. Instead, I'd like to replace the previous search results. I've been struggling to figure out how to accomplish that. I tried adding the `newSearch` state and setting `searchImages: []` and `searchStart: 1` in `handleSubmit`, but neither are making any difference. As a React novice I also tried setting `newSearch` back to false after the image render in the infinite scroll component, which broke the app due to the infinite loop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Parent:

```
export class Images extends Component {
  state = {
    images: [],
    searchImages: [],
    count: 30,
    start: 1,
    searchStart: 1,
    term: '',
    search: false,
    newSearch: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { count, start } = this.state;
      axios
        .get(`/api/photos?count=${count}&start=${start}`)
        .then(res => this.setState({ images: res.data }));
  }

  fetchImages = () => {
    const { count, start, images } = this.state;
    // Will be at 1, then 31 (1 + 30), then 61 (31 + 30), and so forth
    this.setState({ start: start + count });
    axios
      .get(`/api/photos?count=${count}&start=${start}`)
      .then(res =>
        this.setState({ images: images.concat(res.data) })
      );
  }

  fetchSearchImages = () => {
    const { searchStart, count, term, searchImages } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      searchStart: searchStart + count
    });
    axios
      .get(`/api/photos/search?term=${term}&count=${count}&start=${searchStart}`)
      .then(res =>
        this.setState({
          searchImages: searchImages.concat(res.data.results)
        })
      );
  }

  handleSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({
      searchImages: [],
      searchStart: 1,
      search: true,
      newSearch: true
    });

    this.fetchSearchImages();
  }

  handleInputChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      term: e
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>

      <SearchInput onSearch={this.handleInputChange} onFormSubmit={this.handleSubmit} term={this.state.term} />

      <div className="images">
        <InfiniteScroll
          dataLength={this.state.newSearch || this.state.search ? this.state.searchImages.length : this.state.images.length}
          next={this.state.search ? this.fetchSearchImages : this.fetchImages}
          hasMore={true}
          loader={
            <div className="loader-dots">
              <span className="loader-dot"></span>
              <span className="loader-dot"></span>
              <span className="loader-dot"></span>
              <span className="loader-dot"></span>
            </div>
          }
        >
        {this.state.newSearch || this.state.search ? this.state.searchImages.map(image =>
          <Image key={image.id} image={image} />
        ) : this.state.images.map(image =>
          <Image key={image.id} image={image} />
        )}
      </InfiniteScroll>
      </div>

      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Child search component:

```
const SearchInput = props => {

  const onSubmit = e => {
    // Prevents GET request/page refresh on submit
    e.preventDefault();
    props.onFormSubmit();
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <div className="control">
        <input autoFocus value={props.term} onChange={e => props.onSearch(e.target.value)} className="input" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Be aware that the code / repo includes Unsplash API secrets. You should definitely revoke / change them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current code in `fetchSearchImages` is relying on the state before React really sets it. I have sent a PR to your repository to to call `fetchSearchImages` only after the state is set, by using the callback argument of `setState`.

Basically this code

```
handleSubmit = () => {
  this.setState({
    searchImages: [],
    searchStart: 1,
    search: true,
    newSearch: true
  });

  this.fetchSearchImages();
}
```

Needs to be changed to this:

```
handleSubmit = () => {
  this.setState({
    searchImages: [],
    searchStart: 1,
    search: true,
    newSearch: true
  }, this.fetchSearchImages);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your logic, except for this part:

```
this.setState({
      searchImages: searchImages.concat(res.data.results)
})
```

Where you concat your new search results to the previous ones, when all you should do is simply replace them:

```
this.setState({
      searchImages: res.data.results
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer -- that does update the first page of the results, but that part is needed in order for the next page of search results for that term to appear (otherwise the loading animation keeps going when you scroll down). Maybe I can find a workaround for that one thing.
This is controlled by `next={this.state.search ? this.fetchSearchImages : this.fetchImages}` in the `InfiniteScroll` instance.

Comment: Yeah but you don't need it when you are searching for new images, you need it in your `fetchImages` but not your `fetchSearchImages` functions.

Comment: I tried that suggestion (changing to `searchImages: res.data.results` in `fetchSearchImages`and for the same term when you keep scrolling down, it doesn't fetch the new batch of search results for that term, just keeps loading. I think this is because it fetches new results to add to the previous batch for that term, and since it already retrieved the first batch and nothing new is added (`count` stays the same), `searchStart` isn't changed.

Comment: In `fetchImages` there is `images` being used instead of `searchImages`, so maybe there hides some logic error... I think the code changed a bit as well (at least when I first checked out the code from the repo, `fetchSearchImages` wasn't there at all... (and shouldn't be necessary if setting the state is done before calling `fetch[Search]Images`)

Comment: Yeah sorry, I updated the code, updated this question, then restored the code and restored this question :D